# Firebase multipath update fails with permission denied at /

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to make a multipath update at some paths (not at the root (/) path) but I'm getting a warning `@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied` and then an error saying permission denied.

I've given permissions to specified paths.

Obviously if I give permissions to root (/) the update works.

Index.js:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://' + firebaseId + '.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: firebaseId + '.appspot.com',
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "service-account"
  }
});
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userid": {
        "ownerGameId": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()",
          ".write": "((data.val() == null && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')) || ((data.val() != null && newData.val() == null) && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')))"
        },
        "joinedGameId": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()",
          ".write": "((data.val() == null && (auth != null && auth.uid == $userid)) || ((data.val() != null && newData.val() == null) && ((auth != null && auth.uid == $userid) || (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account'))))"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".write": "(data.val() == null && (auth != null && auth.uid == $userid))",
        ".read": "((auth != null && auth.uid == $userid) || (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account'))"
      }
    },
    "not-started-party-game-locations": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": [
        "g"
      ],
      "$id": {
        ".write": "((data.val() == null && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')) || ((data.val() != null && newData.val() == null) && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')))"
      }
    },
    "games": {
      "$gameid": {
        "state": {
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()",
          ".write": "((data.val() == null && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')) || ((data.val() != null && newData.val() != null) && (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account')))"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".write": "(data.val() == null && auth != null)",
        ".read": "(auth != null || (auth != null && auth.uid == 'service-account'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The update I'm trying to do:

```
{ '/users/Hoh2t79MplcG7OTq6QqYpn8AbMz1/joinedGameId': null,
  '/users/Hoh2t79MplcG7OTq6QqYpn8AbMz1/ownerGameId': null,
  '/users/hdD48t58FQRhnbHbdwMprrsuB2x2/joinedGameId': null,
  '/users/hdD48t58FQRhnbHbdwMprrsuB2x2/ownerGameId': null,
  '/games/-LXO8cv2v4BLrPnMeuMh/state': { base: 'cancelled' },
  '/not-started-party-game-locations/-LXO8cv2v4BLrPnMeuMh': null }

admin.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: Without showing your code and security rules, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: @DougStevenson editing my question now as we speak

Comment: You're writing through the Admin SDK, which usually means the code runs with administrative privileges that bypass the security rules. Unless you explicitly chose to disable that behavior, it seems unlikely this code causes the error.

Comment: Note that your rules are quite a bit longer than what I assume it the *minimum* needed to reproduce the problem. Rules are hard enough to read that posting two pages of them makes is less likely that someone will actually find the problem. Is there a way you can reduce them to a more minimal set that still reproduces the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I'm using the admin SDK. I was under the impression that you needed to setup your app with databaseAuthVariableOverride to do writes/reads with a "service-account" uid. I will clean up the rules a little bit.

Comment: If you initialize the SDK with a credentials JSON, it runs with administrative privileges. Running with more restricted privileges requires setting a `databaseAuthVariableOverride`. If you do that in your script, please make sure your question includes that code as it's instrumental to its behavior against security rules.

Comment: Well previously I was getting permission denied when running cloud code with the Admin SDK. So that's why I added `databaseAuthVariableOverride`. I guess it's redundant if you say it has administrative privileges. I see the service account has "Editor" role in IAM. Should that be sufficient to do writes/reads in the db even though there are rules denying?